# During massive Django code reorg, "No module named foobar"; foo and bar are part of my app, but not foobar

Tags: django

I'm doing a massive code reorg of my Django project, to split it into apps.

After having moved a lot of code around, I get this error when I try to run the project:

`Error: no module named foobar`

Note that both `foo` and `bar` are names of Django apps in my project, but I have nothing like `foobar` around.

`grep foobar . -r` = no results.

`find . -name '*foobar*'` = no results.

I'm stumped. Does anybody have ideas?

Comment: Did foobar exist before you reorganized your code? A shot in the dark: Have you tried to delete all *.pyc files in your project?

Comment: With issues like this, the full traceback often shows where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are lacking a comma in your installed app in settings.py between foo and bar

INSTALLED_APPS=['foo','bar']

Comment: +1. The other possibility is that the OP may have `import "foo" "bar"` somewhere else in their code. When you leave out the comma, python concatenates the strings.

Comment: Genius, it was indeed a missing comma in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Thanks!